# How to Mock Azure.Messaging.WebPubSub.WebPubSubServiceClient

Tags: c#, azure, moq, xunit.net, azure-web-pubsub

The class `WebPubSubServiceClient` implements no interface, so how do I mock it?

I could use the decorator pattern like shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74096260/2787333 but then I saw this in the documentation.

> WebPubSubServiceClient()
>
> Initializes a new instance of WebPubSubServiceClient for mocking.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.webpubsub.webpubsubserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-webpubsub-webpubsubserviceclient-ctor

Any suggestions how mocking can be done by using this default constructor?

My end goal is to make a mock that I can use to simulate a response from `WebPubSubServiceClient.GetClientAccessUriAsync(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I feel stupid.

Apparently all Moq needs is a default constructor in the class you want to mock. I always thought an interface was needed .

So this is perfectly fine:

```
using Moq;
using Azure.Messaging.WebPubSub;

...

var webPubSubServiceClientMock = new Mock<WebPubSubServiceClient>();
```